# Exemplos de corpora do português / Examples of corpora of Portuguese

Tags: discussion

### Português

Eu sei que é preferível postar perguntas que sejam mais concretas, ao invés de serem discussões. Mas estive buscando corpora do português e encontrei apenas sites que não eram confiáveis, não estavam acessíveis para busca ou estavam desatualizados (com links quebrados).

Seria possível compilar uma breve lista de corpora do português, preferivelmente com exemplos práticos de como utilizá-las?

---

### English

I know it is preferable to post more concrete questions, as opposed to open discussions. But I have been searching for corpora of Portuguese and I have only come across sites that are either untrustworthy, not openly searchable or outdated (with broken links).

Would it be possible to compile a brief list of corpora of Portuguese, preferably with practical examples of how to use them?

Comment: Maybe do this on meta? Eventually we'll probably want a collective resource base, like [here on Japanese.SE](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese). In any case, I think resource questions should be on meta (and I voted to close for automatic migration).

Comment: I understand and appreciate your point. However, I can't really state how valuable resource questions have been to me on Stackoverflow. Perhaps segregating those questions to meta dilutes the main site's relevance. Then again, this is just my two cents on it.

Comment: O que é corpora do português?

Comment: Sure, we can decide to keep them on main if everyone agrees. As for your question, the [CRPC](http://www.clul.ul.pt/en/researcher/183-reference-corpus-of-contemporary-portuguese-crpc) is openly searchable with the last update as recently as 2012. It's maintained by the linguistics department at the University of Lisbon, so I judge it to be trustworthy, too. Are the links really not working for you? (Maybe just try accessing it via a search engine.)

Comment: @MarcosSartorato Sendo corpora o plural de corpus, "corpus linguístico é o conjunto de textos escritos e registros orais em uma determinada língua e que serve como base de análise". Fonte: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_lingu%C3%ADstico

Comment: Ah, entendi... Nunca vi um desses.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Would you like to post CRPC as an answer? We could start a list from there. I have found it to be trustworthy as well, but loading the website requires a couple of nudges from time to time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the suggestion in the comments, I would like to mention two corpora I found.

#### CRPC (Corpus de Referência do Português Contemporâneo)

(Maintained by the *Centro de Linguística da Universidade de Lisboa*.)

*Links*

- home page ([EN](http://www.clul.ul.pt/resources/183-reference-corpus-of-contemporary-portuguese-crpc)) ([PT](http://www.clul.ul.pt/pt/recursos/183-reference-corpus-of-contemporary-portuguese-crpc))
- [corpora overview](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/)
- latest version [CRPC v2.3 POS fine-grained](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/crpcfg15/)

*Features/Notes*

- 309 million words
- POS (parts of speech) matching ([syntax overview](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/doc/Simple_query_language.pdf))
- 93.5% European Portuguese (but also searchable by region)

[image]

---

#### Corpus do Português

(Maintained by Mark Davies¹ (*Brigham Young University*) & Michael Ferreira (*Georgetown University*).)

<sub>¹ Mark Davies also created the well-known and widely used *Corpus of Contemporary American English* (COCA)</sub>

*Links*

- [homepage](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/)
- Wikipedia entry [Corpus do Português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_do_Portugu%C3%AAs)

*Features*

- 45 million words (to be extended to 1 billion words)
- sources from 1300s–1900s
- searchable by register and region
- POS matching