# Should we allow reference questions on main?

Tags: discussion

We have two "reference requests" so far:

- [Online Portuguese dictionary with IPA transcriptions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/483/online-portuguese-dictionary-with-ipa-transcriptions)
- [Exemplos de corpora do português / Examples of corpora of Portuguese](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/exemplos-de-corpora-do-portugu%C3%AAs-examples-of-corpora-of-portuguese?cb=1)

Both questions were initially asked on main. The latter was closed/migrated by the community to meta. The former was closed (and later reopened for lack of clear consensus).

This has also been brought up here: [About community wiki or protected questions used only for reference (usually breaking some site rules)](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/about-community-wiki-or-protected-questions-used-only-for-reference-usually-bre)

Good reference requests can be a very valuable resource and I think it's a good time to think about how we want to handle them. There are several options:

1. On main, just like questions (and tagged [referência](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refer%c3%aancia))
2. On main, but only as community wiki (i.e. no reputation)
3. On meta, as question
4. On meta, as community wiki (as collaborative project)

I think the difficulty lies in formulating a policy that allows any Good Reference Request®, and disallows *bad* reference requests (like "what's a good website to learn Portuguese").

The difficulty can also be circumvented by having a custom close reason (like "this is not a useful reference request") and closing any bad reference request as "bad, because [I know a bad reference request when I see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)"... but we would still need some guideline that tells us when to vote to close.

Anyway, I hope people will post some ideas. I'll post some of the models I'm familiar with from other SE sites.

---

Temos duas perguntas sobre referências.

- [Online Portuguese dictionary with IPA transcriptions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/483/online-portuguese-dictionary-with-ipa-transcriptions)
- [Exemplos de corpora do português / Examples of corpora of Portuguese](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167/exemplos-de-corpora-do-portugu%C3%AAs-examples-of-corpora-of-portuguese?cb=1)

As duas perguntas foram postadas no site principal. A segunda foi fechada/migrada pela comunidade para o meta. A primeira foi fechada (e reaberta por falta de consenso).

Pergunta relacionada: [About community wiki or protected questions used only for reference (usually breaking some site rules)](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/about-community-wiki-or-protected-questions-used-only-for-reference-usually-bre)

Boas solicitações de referências podem ser fontes muito valiosas, e eu acho que seria um bom momento de se pensar em como lidaremos com esse tipo de pergunta. Temos várias opções:

1. No site principal e como pergunta normal (com a tag [referência](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refer%c3%aancia))
2. No site principal, mas como "community wiki" (sem ganhar reputação)
3. No meta, como pergunta
4. No meta, como "community wiki" (como um projeto colaborativo)

Eu acho que a dificuldade está em formular uma política que permita *boas* solicitações de referência, e desaprove solicitações *ruins* (como "what's a good website to learn Portuguese" — "que site é bom para aprender português").

Podemos contornar o problema com um motivo de fechamento personalizado (como "esta não é uma boa pergunta sobre referências"), e fechando solicitações ruins de referências... mas ainda assim precisaríamos de uma diretriz que nos diga quando votar para fechar.

De qualquer modo, espero que o pessoal poste algumas ideias. Eu vou apresentar alguns dos modelos que conheço de outras comunidades SE.

Comment: @Jacinto Poderia me ajudar com o português? (Pode ser pt_PT se quiser.) Obrigado!

Comment: Posso te ajudar também? :)

Comment: Teria tido todo o gosto, mas o Bruno já tratou disso. Já agora, eu não recebi notificação do teu comentário. Creio que o @ + nome só funciona quando a pessoa já tem um comentário no mesmo post. Vi isto por acaso.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Thank you! (Well, at least I tried ;)

Comment: @Jacinto Me desculpe se fui enxerido, é que eu estava disponível e vi o texto com erros...

Comment: @Bruno Ora essa! Fizeste muito bem, eu não tenho, nem quero ter, o exclusivo da revisão de perguntas. Possivelmente o Earthling pediu-me a mim porque eu já uma vez tinha revisto uma resposta dele. Agora vou ver "enxerido" no dicionário :)

Comment: Só chamei o Jacinto porque ele ofereceu a sua ajuda [aqui](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/981/viagem-ou-viajem/982#comment2688_982).

Comment: A third reference question: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/tabela-dos-fonemas-com-exemplos-de-sonoridade

Comment: [tag:referência] would be a meta-tag, wouldn't it?

Comment: These questions are tagged as [tag:recursos].

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion the reference questions should be:

- On the main site;
- Community Wiki;
- And *possibly* locked.

Like this example in german.SE: [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german).

## Community Wiki

References might not age well; we want the community to feel free to refresh them.

References might not be complete; we want the community to improve the answers, even if those improvements will change the original answer.
Conservative users (myself included) might hesitate in changing someone else's answer.

And if the edit is not consensual, it can always be rolled back.

## Locked?

If they follow a particular format, they should be locked so no one breaks the format.
See the [example](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german) I gave above: users adding new answers would break and corrupt the format.

If they don't follow a specific format, we probably would not want to lock them.

## Main site

### List is known by more than just power-users

If they are on meta, they will only be known to the power users.
No new or irregular user will ever find them.

### Natural location

It's the natural place to ask, for new users or those not familiar with the StackExchange network's *modus operandi*.

New users will post reference questions on the main site even if they belong on meta; then they will be closed as off-topic, and someone will (hopefully) post a comment on their question, directing them to the meta post.
Posting them on the main site prevents this.

### Affluence of interested users

These questions will show up on online searches of these resources.
Those interested in these resources are trying to improve their Portuguese, and that's (part of) our target audience. :)

Comment: @bad_coder "se uma alternativa a 'trancar o thread' seria gerível do ponto de vista de um mod": qual alternativa?, e como posso eu saber se essa alternativa desconhecida pode ser gerida? Queres re-escrever a frase, a ver se a percebo melhor?

Comment: Apaguei, estive a pensar nisso. 2 hipoteses: 1º"proteger a thread", 2º"fechar a thread". Acho que a primera é a mais prática e talvez nem desse problemas. A segunda era manter a thread fechada no site principal, e um utilizar que quisesse fazer uma alteração alterar um "duplicado" (ou tipo sandbox) aqui no meta (que depois era integrado no main). Mas talvez tal nem seja preciso, com roll-backs, votos, apagar posts e edição era sempre possivel manter a thread em bom estado. Não sei, o JorgeB levantou o problema de "manutenção coplicada" e eu estava a tentar propor hipoteses sobre isso...

Comment: (Este comentário vou apagar) hoje postei na outra thread do Stafuza -sobre o mesmo assunto- uma reposta em muito semelhante à tua. A razão é que preciso de fazer uma pergunta sobre gramaticas "open source" em Português que possam ser citadas com alguma abundância num site terceiro sem probs de direitos de autor. Ora, a pergunta podia ser feita noutros sites do SE mas francamente acho que não vão saber responder tão bem como aqui - por ser em Português.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view this type of questions should be in meta as CW because this questions are very difficult to maintain and can lose their quality quickly. Maybe one or two of these questions can be on main site but we can not make this the rule.

---

No meu ponto de vista este tipo de perguntas devem estar no meta como CW porque estas questões são muito difíceis de manter e podem perder a sua qualidade rapidamente. Talvez uma ou duas destas perguntas pode estar no site principal, mas não podemos fazer disso a regra.

Comment: Why as CW? Votes here grant no rep, so are you just thinking that CW invites folks to edit liberally?

Comment: @Frank Community Wiki just because I think that type of answers are difficult to maintain and we have to do a Community Work to maintain them.

Comment: `eu também não sou de acordo com perguntas de recursos principalmente porque normalmente são baseadas em links e ficam desatualizadas facilmente` <-- This is a strong argument, and I think that it would strengthen this answer.

Comment: I think it works well on other sites. Even the answers on Stack Overflow also age, not because of rotten links only, but because compilers and software in general is continuously developed, so better solutions appear all the time. And the community there has no problem keeping the answers current, updating them whenever needed.

Comment: I think your points are not without reason, however I do agree with other posters in that difficulties can be managed (with a collective policy where experienced users and mods collaborate to keep things in good order.)