# Resources for etymological research―Recursos para investigação etimológica

Tags: discussion, recursos

I’m quite fond of history of phrases, words, and even spelling, and after a year and so here I’ve located quite a few useful resources for research on these subjects (no quite sure we can call all this ‘etymology’, but I need a short title), which I’m quite happy to share.

Now there is [this discussion](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/should-we-allow-reference-questions-on-main/203#203) on whether questions about resources should be on main or meta. But rather than wait for a conclusion to be reached on the right location for such questions, maybe we should go ahead with it, say here on meta? We can always change location later if necessary. What do you guys think?

---

### Português

Eu gosto particularmente de história de expressões, palavras e até grafias, e ao longo de um ano e tal aqui, encontrei uma porção de recursos úteis para este tipo de questões (não tenho a certeza se podemos chamar ‘etimologia’ a tudo isto, mas precisava de um título curto), os quais gostaria de partilhar.

Agora, há [aqui esta discussão](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/should-we-allow-reference-questions-on-main/203#203) sobre se perguntas sobre recursos devem estar no site principal ou no meta. Mas em vez de esperar por uma conclusão acerca da localização certa para questões deste tipo, que tal avançar com a questão de recursos etimológicos, por exemplo aqui no meta? Podemos sempre mudar a localização mais tarde se necessário.

Comment: Acho a ideia fantástica e, de fato, é algo de que eu sempre senti falta. O Google Books nunca me leva tão longe quanto eu gostaria.

Comment: @Ramon Então olha, eu tenho por aí umas perguntas de etimologia ainda por responder :)

Comment: Aguardando ansiosamente pelas respostas :)

Answer (score 11):

Oh! what a phantabulastic idea! Pure genius! I’ll get ahead with it straight away. I’ll write the substantive answer in Portuguese only for the time being. I reckon anyone interested in this type of resources will be able to understand my answer. Let me know if you need any help.

---

### Corpora:

[**Corpo Informatizado do Português Medieval (CIPM)**](http://cipm.fcsh.unl.pt/). Contém uma grande coleção de poesia medieval, textos legais e outros textos dos séculos XIII a XV.

[**Corpus do Português**](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/). A vertente histórica tem uma grande quantidade de literatura dos séculos XIII ao XX, e ainda imprensa dos anos 90 do século XX. Contém muito material do CIPM, mas mostra apenas excertos, enquanto o CIPM mostra o texto completo.

---

### Dicionários Antigos

**Raphael Bluteau, *Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino*, 1712-28**. Dicionário em oito volumes (1712-21) mais dois suplementos (1727-8). Download: [Biblioteca Brasiliana Guita e José Mindlin](http://www.brasiliana.usp.br/search?order=DESC&rpp=10&sort_by=score&page=2&group_by=none&etal=0&view=listing&fq=dc.contributor.author:%22Bluteau,%20Rafael,%201638-1734%22); Consulta online: [Biblioteca Nacional de Portugal](http://de.bnportugal.pt/L2771-80/).

**Antonio de Moraes Silva, *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*, 1789**. Download: [Biblioteca Brasiliana Guita e José Mindlin](http://www.brasiliana.usp.br/search?filtertype=dc.title_t&filter=diccionario%20da%20lingua%20portugueza&submit_search-filter-controls_add=Buscar). O dicionário foi tendo várias edições até 1959. Por vezes é interessante comparar várias. Encontrei disponíveis para download no Google Books a 2ª edição (1813), a 4ª (1831) e a 6ª (1858). Podem encontrar o primeiro volume (A-E) [aqui](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22uma%20pe%C3%A7a%20de%20cama%22&num=50&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk9baw8NXRAhUCVhQKHa31B54Q_AUIDCgF&biw=1242&bih=580) e o segundo (F-Z) [aqui (2ª e 4ª edições)](https://www.google.pt/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22uma%20serpente%20Brasilica%22&oq=%22uma%20serpente%20Brasilica%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.9505j0j9)  e [aqui (6ª edição)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lTBxS8oISF4C&pg=PA355&dq=movimento%20em%20todas%20as%20direc%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20de%20todo%20corpo%20organizado&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFuef88tXRAhUGchQKHXz_Ap4Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=movimento%20em%20todas%20as%20direc%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20de%20todo%20corpo%20organizado&f=false)

Só letra A: **Diccionario da Lingoa Portugueza da Academia Real das Sciencias de Lisboa, 1793**. Leitura e download: [Biblioteca Nacional de Portugal](http://purl.pt/29130/3/#/10). Só tem a letra A, mas faz uma apresentação exaustiva e repleta de citações de todas as nuances da palavra e expressões em que entra.

**Frei Domingos Vieira, *Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza*, 1871-74**, em cinco volumes. Download: [blog Arquivo Digital 7cv](http://arquivodigital-7cv.blogspot.pt/2010/09/grande-diccionario-portuguez-ou.html). Volumes: 1ª – A-B; 2ª – C-D; 3ª – E-L; 4º - M-P; 5º - Q-Z.

**Cândido de Figueiredo, *Nôvo Dicionário da Língua Portuguêsa*, 1899 (1ª edição) e 1913 (2ª edição)**. Edição de 1913: Download: [Dicionário Aberto](http://www.dicionario-aberto.net/dict.pdf); Consulta online (a grafia nem sempre corresponde à original): [Dicionário Aberto](http://www.dicionario-aberto.net/browse). Edição de 1899, só 1º volume (A-I). Leitura online e download: [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/novodiccionriod00figugoog). Até agora as únicas diferenças que detetei entre as duas edições foram umas ligeiras na grafia. A edição de 1899 usou uma acentuação gráfica radicalmente diferente da corrente na altura (a que se encontra no *Thesouro* de 1871-74), nomeadamente usando acentos para indicar a sílaba tónica. Muitos destes acentos vieram a ser adotados oficialmente em Portugal em 1911 e no Brasil em 1943.

Answer (score 2):

**Dicionários Etimológicos do séc XX**

Duas notáveis ausências, que são no entanto obras de referência e merecem ser incluídos:

**José Pedro Machado**, ***Dicionário etimológico da língua portuguesa : com a mais antiga documentação escrita e conhecida de muitos dos vocábulos estudados.*** Várias edições: 1ª([1952](http://id.bnportugal.gov.pt/bib/porbase/1747984)-[1956-1959](http://id.bnportugal.gov.pt/bib/porbase/1246420)), 2ª(1967), 4ª([1987](http://id.bnportugal.gov.pt/bib/porbase/2430270)), 6ª([1990](http://id.bnportugal.gov.pt/bib/porbase/487656)), 7ª([1995](http://id.bnportugal.gov.pt/bib/porbase/1683978)).

**Antenor Nascentes**, ***Dicionário Etimológico da Lingua Portuguesa***. Primeira edição [1932](http://id.bnportugal.gov.pt/bib/porbase/1254106). Pode ser consultado: [aqui](https://archive.org/details/AntenorNascentesDicionaroEtimologicoDaLinguaPortuguesaTomoI/page/n2/mode/2up).

Comment: Excelentes adições.